# php dollar sign in ini files

Tags: php, escaping, ini

I'm trying to parse an ini file with the [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) function.

Reserved characters are `?{}|&~![()^`.

PHP arrays can have keys with a dollar sign, but why can't this function generate an array with keys from an ini file that has `$` characters?

Comment: Why do you say it can't?
Are you sure that a name with a $ is correct in .ini files?

Comment: Give some example fro your .ini file , row where you have variable and value with $ sign problem.

Comment: ini file:
`key$ = value`

Comment: @artragis i didn't find any information about $ in ini files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its perhaps because the use of $ is used to specify INI variable; thus causing a syntax error if not used in the context of a variable

Using `${...}` as a value will look to

1. An INI setting
2. An environment variable

For example:

```
<?php
print_r(parse_ini_string('
php_ext_dir = ${extension_dir}
operating_system = ${OS}
'));
?>

Array
(
    [php_ext_dir] => ./ext/
    [operating_system] => Windows_NT
)
```

Comment: I see that it replaces the values but not keys.